# Unable to get the value of variable inside a variable in azure release pipeline

Tags: bash, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to use a variable inside variable in azure release pipelines.

i am using `classic editor with bash extension` for that. Bash `task version is 3.*`

```
input=my-name-is-$(customer)  
echo $input
```

`$(customer)` will be an user input provided when i create a release. ex: `customer: foo`
There is also a variable called `my-name-is-foo: bar` in the release pipeline associated variable group.

Current output is this:
`my-name-is-foo`

Expected output is this:
`bar`

I have tried using
`${{ input }}`    : `bad substitution`
`$(${{ input }})` : `bad substitution`

In bash script, i know we can use something like

```
${!input}
```

which will get you the original value: `bar`
Is there any syntax that needs to be followed in azure release pipeline ?

Comment: Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer can help you resolve the issue.

Comment: It is resolved. Thank you.

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT can i use multiple variables instead of one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description, you need to use nested variable in Release Pipeline.

Example: `$($(input))`

I am afraid that there is no built-in method in release pipeline can achieve this.

To meet your requirement, you can use the Variable Set task from extension: [Variable Toolbox](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jessehouwing.jessehouwing-vsts-variable-tasks).

Here is an example:

[image]

```
Variable name: CustomName

Value: $(my-name-is-$(customer))
```

**Result:** We can use the format:`$(variablename)` get the Nested variable value in the next task.

[image]